# How to get PropertyInfo of C# object

Tags: c#, propertyinfo

I am trying to extract the PropertyInfo of an object but the propertyInfo returns no properties:

```
 [TestMethod]
    public void TestGetValueMethod()
    {
      var value = 23;
      System.Reflection.PropertyInfo[] propertyInfo = value.GetType ().GetProperties();
      //DTOPropertyInfo info = new DTOPropertyInfo(propertyInfo[0]);
      System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(propertyInfo.Length);
    }
```

propertyInfo.Length returns 0. What am I missing?

Comment: Value is a local variable, not a property member. You should probably start by reading a good book.

Comment: What do you expect it to print?

Comment: `value` is in `int`, and does not contain any properties. You can confirm this by reviewing the documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32(v=vs.110).aspx. What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: Try to assign a `string` to `value`. Then you will see that there are some public properties when you call `GetProperties`.

Comment: @atlaste, You should probably start by reading the question. OP is not using value as a property member. Value is a local variable, but OP uses "GetType()" to obtain the type from that variable, and fetch the properties from the type. However, value is of type int, which doesn't have any properties.

Comment: Perhaps consider deleting the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string test = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

        // Get a PropertyInfo object representing the Chars property.
        PropertyInfo pinfo = typeof(string).GetProperty("Chars");

        // Show the first, seventh, and last letters
        ShowIndividualCharacters(pinfo, test, 0, 6, test.Length - 1);

        // Show the complete string.
        Console.Write("The entire string: ");
        for (int x = 0; x < test.Length; x++)
        {
            Console.Write(pinfo.GetValue(test, new Object[] {x}));
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }

    static void ShowIndividualCharacters(PropertyInfo pinfo, 
                                         object value,
                                         params int[] indexes)
    {
       foreach (var index in indexes) 
          Console.WriteLine("Character in position {0,2}: '{1}'",
                            index, pinfo.GetValue(value, new object[] { index }));
       Console.WriteLine();                          
    }                                      
}
```